# How to select specific file using CfileDialog in MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I would like to open a file dialog and allow user to select only the file with name "myapplication.ini" and user can only browse folder's to check if the file is existing to select it.

so i came across CFileDialog which would do almost what i want other than limiting it to display only files with name "myapplication.ini"

currently my usage of CFiledialog

`CFileDialog FileDialog(TRUE,"features.ini", NULL,OFN_HIDEREADONLY,NULL);`

I am not sure what could should be changed to make it work as i expected.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the filter string like this:

```
static TCHAR BASED_CODE szFilter[] = _T("features.ini (features.ini)|features.ini|");
```

and then pass it to your `CFileDialog` ctor:

```
CFileDialog FileDialog(TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_HIDEREADONLY, szFilter);
```

Comment: it worked after i chnage the szFilter argument to the correct argument,edited your answer.Thanks

Comment: The user types `*` into the filename edit box, presses enter, and all the files are revealed.

Comment: You can solve that by deriving from CFileDialog, overriding OnInitDone method with the following code:
CWnd* dlgitm = GetParent()->GetDlgItem(edt1);
dlgitm->EnableWindow(FALSE);

This will disable the editing of the textbox text.
cheers mate

Comment: You could do that, but won't it confuse the user? I know I'd be perplexed to be offered a file dialog with an edit box, but then find that the edit box was disabled.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a poor UI. Even if you filter out all but that file, the user can override the filter. If you aren't going to allow the user to make a choice of file name, why ask them for their choice?

What you are actually doing, in my view, is asking the user to select a folder. So instead of the file dialog, show them a folder selection dialog, `CFolderPickerDialog`.

Comment: End user has to select the file from his location and my application will accept only with the specific filename.So i had to restrict it.

Comment: I understand fully. So ask the user to select the **location** rather than the **file**. Use a folder selection dialog and not a file selection dialog.

Comment: Yes, this would be my preferred solution too, @David is absolutely correct, a file dialog is the wrong way to go. +1.

Comment: But from a user perspective it would be nice to know if the specific file is in said folder.